# jQuery - run script when window is scrolled in 90%

Tags: jquery

I found a nice script which load content of page when user is scrolling the page. URL of this article: [CLICK HERE](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/auto-load-records-on-page-scroll)

I have one problem with this script - it's run when user scroll page in 100% (when scroll is on the bottom). I would like to start this script when the scroll will in 90% of the page.

Here is original code:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
```

I tried like that:

```
    var percent = 90;
    window_scrolled = ((percent/$(document).height())*100);
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() <= window_scrolled)  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
```

but it's doesn't work. Why? Where is a problem in my script?

Comment: I think, a problem is in to my script because I make an mistake but I don't know how exactly.

Comment: The link I gave was about zoom, not scroll. My fault. I deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the full code:

```
var percent = 90;
var window_scrolled;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    window_scrolled = ($(document).height()/100)*90;

    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= window_scrolled) {
        alert("scrolled to bottom");
    }
});
```

First of all, you were doing the maths wrong. If we say that the document height is 2000px, your code would return 4.5, instead of 1800, so:

```
((percent/$(document).height())*100)
```

becomes:

```
(($(document).height()/100)*percent)
```

And, this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() <= window_scrolled)
```

becomes this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() => window_scrolled)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second block of code, your `window_scrolled` calculation is not correct to be 90% of the document height.  You are computing `0.9 / height` when you should be computing `0.9 * height`.

It also looks to me like the comparison against `window_scrolled` is backwards and should be `>=` instead of `<=`.

I think you want this:

```
var percent = 90;
var window_scrolled = (percent * $(document).height()) / 100;

if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= window_scrolled) {
    // at least part of the last 10% of the document is visible
}
```